PyQt6 crashes when trying to edit a cell in a QTableWidget when using setCellWidget on Wayland
EDIT: This has been fixed in the Qt 6.7 update.
If I run the code below, and then try to edit the first cell, either by double-clicking or by beginning to type, the window freezes and closes with Segmentation fault (core dumped) as output.
This is fixed if I disable editing the cells or if PyQt5 is used instead.
It does not crash if I unset the WAYLAND_DISPLAY environment variable to force the program to run in Xwayland instead (or at least that's what I think it does), doing so prints:
Failed to create wl_display (Connection refused)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.

Although it still works.
I want to be able to display an image inside of a cell in a table.
I tried to do that by creating a label, setting its pixmap to the image and then using table.setCellWidget, but then I ran into this issue.
This seems like a PyQt6 / Qt bug but if it isn't, is there a way to fix this without using the fixes shown above?
Here are my PyQt6 versions if it matters (I have tried both installing with pip and using the system packages provided by the package manager):
PyQt6      6.6.1
PyQt6-Qt6  6.6.3
PyQt6-sip  13.6.0

Code:
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets


class Crash(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Crash")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.show()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["text", "widget"])

        self.table.insertRow(0)
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("text"))

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.table.setCellWidget(0, 1, widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Crash()
    app.exec()

The 2 log files after enabling logging as mentioned here:
xwayland
wayland

PyQt has almost certainly nothing to do with it, and it probably is a Qt/Wayland bug. The mouse event is probably not properly handled when partially ignored in the widget tree (QWidget and QLabel by default do not accept mouse events). If you can, test it with PySide6 and consider filing a bug on https://bugreports.qt.io/. Note that, in reality, a more appropriate way to show images in Qt item views is by setting a QPixmap as the Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole of the item, or by using a custom item delegate.

@musicamante it still crashes with PySide6. I might file a bug report. Using the Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole of the item seems to work, thanks!

EDIT: This has been fixed in the Qt 6.7 update.
Thanks to @musicamante, I managed to get an image to work using Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole instead.
New Code:
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Crash(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Crash")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.show()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["text", "widget"])

        self.table.insertRow(0)
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("text"))

        # set img with Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole instead
        img_path = "img.png"
        img = QtGui.QPixmap(img_path)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole, img)
        self.table.setItem(0, 1, item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Crash()
    app.exec()



